# Full isomorphism-closed reflective subcategory of Set

Tags: category-theory

What are the full isomorphism-closed [reflective subcategories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of $\textbf{Set}$?

In the book "[The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.htm)" it is mentioned (p. 58) that there are precisely three such subcategories.  I can see two of them are:

1. the whole category $\textbf{Set}$
2. the subcategory consisting of all singletons

What would be the third one?

Comment: Hmm...what about $\emptyset$, i.e. the subcategory with object $\emptyset$ and the unique morphism $\emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset$?

Comment: @uncookedfalcon I don't think $\emptyset$ is a reflective subcategory of $\textbf{Set}$.  Because given a nonempty set $A$, there is no morphism from $A$ to $\emptyset$, hence no reflection morphism.

Comment: Ahh...fantastic point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subcategory containing the singletons and the empty set seems to work.

Comment: I think you are right.  The category you mention works.  But that makes me think, maybe I was mistaken: the subcategory consisting of only the singletons is not reflective?  Because if there were a reflection arrow from $\emptyset$ to some singleton $A$, it would have to be the empty function.  But the empty function $\emptyset \to \emptyset$ does not factor through that map $\emptyset \to A$.  What do you think?

Comment: sorry about the confusion: the subcategory consisting of only the singletons is reflective after all.  Only the functions to a object in the subcategory need to be considered in the definition of reflection arrow.